# How to get text from <p> using Jsoup

Tags: java, parsing, jsoup

To be short. I have following code:

```
elements.select("#offers_table > tbody > tr:nth-child(2) > td > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(2) > td:nth-child(1) > div > p.color-9.lheight16.marginbott5.x-normal").get(0).toString();
```

and I am getting

```
<p class="color-9 lheight16 marginbott5 x-normal"> This is the text I would like to get </p>
```

How to get

> This is the text I would like to get

from here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`element.text()`](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/Element.html#text()) where `element` is your *Element*.